# Unity assignment of children to parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I have a trouble with correct assignment game object to parent. When I use the code below, some part of created game objects are assigned to "PlayerArea" and the rest to "PlaceForCars". How do I make it so that all objects are assigned to "PlaceForCars"?

```
void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        GameObject toInstantiate = Automobile[0];
        GameObject instance = Instantiate(toInstantiate);
        instance.transform.SetParent(PlayerArea.transform.FindChild("PlaceForCars"));
        instance.transform.position = instance.transform.parent.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is? What part of your code isn't working? What are you intending to do, and how does your code fail to achieve your objectives?

Comment: The problem is that some of the created objects are assigned to "PlayerArea" instead of "PlaceForCars", otherwise the code works well. 
Creates ten objects, but why are not all assigned to the "PlaceForCars"?

The hierarchy should look like "PlayerArea / PlaceForCars / Created Objects" after loop end.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Does it consistently misplace the same number of objects each time? If you add logging for `PlayerArea.transform.FindChild("PlaceForCars")` in the loop, does the result change randomly?

Comment: Number of assigned objects is random, but logging turned me ten times the same (PlaceForCars)

Comment: Something else to note, though probably not related - `FindChild()` is deprecated, you should probably use `Find()` instead if you need that functionality.